# Progressive background change - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to progressively change the background color 3 times.

For example, I want it to gradually go from blue to grey to purple. Currently, the background transitions as expected from blue to grey.

Trying to illustrate it:

```
= Blue
==
===
====
===== Grey
====
===
==
= Purple
```

Could someone please help me make it go from grey to purple after the first transition please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    var animation_begin_pos = 0;
    var animation_mid_pos = 500;
    var animation_end_pos = 1000;
    var beginning_color = new $.Color( 'rgb(0,156,243)' );
    var middle_color = new $.Color( 'rgb(36,40,47)' );
    var ending_color = new $.Color( 'rgb(97,20,204)' );

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        if( scroll_pos >= animation_begin_pos && scroll_pos < animation_mid_pos ) { 
            var percentScrolled = scroll_pos / ( animation_mid_pos - animation_begin_pos );
            var newRed = beginning_color.red() + ( ( middle_color.red() - beginning_color.red() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newGreen = beginning_color.green() + ( ( middle_color.green() - beginning_color.green() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newBlue = beginning_color.blue() + ( ( middle_color.blue() - beginning_color.blue() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newColor = new $.Color( newRed, newGreen, newBlue );
            $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
            // messes up starting here
        } else if ( scroll_pos >= animation_mid_pos && scroll_pos <= animation_end_pos ) {
            scroll_ps = $(document).height() - $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).height();
            var percentScrolled = scroll_pos / ( animation_end_pos - animation_mid_pos );
            var newRed = middle_color.red() + ( ( ending_color.red() - middle_color.red() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newGreen = middle_color.green() + ( ( ending_color.green() - middle_color.green() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newBlue = middle_color.blue() + ( ( ending_color.blue() - middle_color.blue() ) * percentScrolled );
            var newColor = new $.Color( newRed, newGreen, newBlue );
            $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: newColor }, 0);
        } else if ( scroll_pos > animation_end_pos ) {
             $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: ending_color }, 0);
        } else if ( scroll_pos < animation_begin_pos ) {
             $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: beginning_color }, 0);
        } else { }
    });
});
```

Comment: I played around a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldgevs6r/ The issue is that around the switch from gray to purple as you can see in the fiddle the percentage jumps from .998 to .5 so it makes the initial starting switch too big of a change and its super noticeable. I will play around with it more later and see if I can figure out a way to normalize that value across the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be, if you calculated the scroll position into a number in range from 0 to 1 and have your colors in a list.

With that you can then calculate which two colors to pick (`colors[n]` and `colors[n+1]`) and how much you need to mix them (`color1*(1-f)+color2*f`).

```
// list of colors
var colors = [
    new $.Color('rgb(0,156,243)'),
    new $.Color('rgb(36,40,47)'),
    new $.Color('rgb(97,20,204)')
];
$(document).scroll(function() {
    // calculate scroll position 0-1
    var scroll_pos = $(document).scrollTop();
    var height =  $(document).outerHeight();
    var body_height = $(window).height();
    var pos = scroll_pos/(height-body_height);

    // calculate which colors to pick and how much to mix them
    pos *= colors.length-1;

    var n = Math.floor(pos);
    var f = pos % 1;

    // prevent getting out of bounds color pick
    if (n > colors.length-2)
    {
        n = colors.length-2
        f = 1
    }

    // pick colors
    var color1 = colors[n]
    var color2 = colors[n+1];

    // mix the two colors
    var color = new $.Color(
          Math.floor(color1.red()*(1-f) + color2.red()*f),
          Math.floor(color1.green()*(1-f) + color2.green()*f),
          Math.floor(color1.blue()*(1-f) + color2.blue()*f)
    );

    // set the background color
    $("body").css("background", color);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqnvusbh/)

Answer (score 1):

Created a function so that it would work with any amount of listed colors as long as they have an ordered stop value between 0 and 1.

```
var colorList = [
    { 
        color: new $.Color('rgb(0,156,243)'),
        stop: 0 
    }, { 
        color: new $.Color('rgb(36,40,47)'),
        stop: 0.25
    }, { 
        color: new $.Color('rgb(97,20,204)'),
        stop: 0.5
    }, { 
        color: new $.Color('rgb(36,40,47)'),
        stop: 0.75
    }, { 
        color: new $.Color('rgb(0,156,243)'),
        stop: 1
    }
];

function getGradientColor(colorList, percent) 
{ 
    percent = 0 || percent;  

    if (colorList.length < 1)
    {
       return new $.Color();
    }

    for (var n = colorList.length - 1; n > 0; n--)
    {       
        if (percent >= colorList[n].stop) { break; }
    }

    if (n > colorList.length - 2)
    {
        n = colorList.length - 2;
        f = 1;
    }

    var f = Math.min((percent - colorList[n].stop) / (colorList[n+1].stop - colorList[n].stop), 1);

    var color1 = colorList[n].color;
    var color2 = colorList[n+1].color;

    return new $.Color(
        Math.floor(color1.red()*(1-f) + color2.red()*f),
        Math.floor(color1.green()*(1-f) + color2.green()*f),
        Math.floor(color1.blue()*(1-f) + color2.blue()*f)
    );
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop(); 
    var height =  $('.tall').outerHeight();
    var body_height = $(window).height();

    // Ensure no divide by 0
    var percent = (height > 0 ? scrollPosition / (height - body_height) : 0);

    $("body").css("background", getGradientColor(colorList, percent));
}).trigger("scroll");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fse62fpd/